Chrome cannot connect to target url from a docker container
We have a Jenkins job which runs test automation using Selenium.
The job starts a Docker container using a Docker image which is based on jenkins/inbound-agent and Google Chrome is installed.
My problem is, while the test automation works well on local desktop environment (without containers), the target site is not reachable by Google Chrome in the container. It says "ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED"
"curl " command works well from both host and container's shell.
If the job runs the automation with a container with Firefox, it works well.
And Chrome also works well if I run it on host.
Host is RHEL 7.x, Docker's version is 24.x
Where should I check?
